# Conditional based (selective documents from mongo) indexing to elasticsearch from mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, indexing

Use case
Need to index selective documents from a mongo collection. Selection is based on the document field value. Eg., Profile collection has multiple documents, but need to index documents whose age > 25 and country is "US"
I am using mongo-connector for indexing collection (in elasticsearch)

Please suggest the approaches which can be taken?

Answer (score 0):

> Need to index selective documents

Using elasticsearch you decide which fields to index through mapping. So in your case, you can set all the fields except `age` to `index: no`

[Elastic Search Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of your mongo-connector, you could also use namespaces to select which documents to index. See the [Configuration Options](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration-Options) of mongo-connector. However, I don't think that conditional index is possible... at least I have never seen it.